# Limitations of static rendering when delivering logged in experiences to non-auth endpoints

Tags: gatsby, server-side-rendering

I've been using the awesome static site renderer, gatsby, for a while now, but I am confronted with a use case where it may not be best for any static site generator and I was wondering if there was a standard practice for dealing with this problem.

The problem is: is it possible to deliver slightly different experiences for the same URLs based on if you're logged in or not?

Take for example https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby. If you are logged out, you see a button that stars the repository. When you are logged in and have starred it however, you see "Unstar."

And from looking at the source, it appears to be in the initial payload from the server.

But for that to work, you need a server that can 1.) determine whether or not you are logged in and 2.) based on your profile / preferences / data display certain content.

It seems that the only way to deliver a slightly different experience is to render the static content and then alter it once the javascript runs / calls are made to authenticate, which is less than ideal.

Maybe that initial render could check the presence of a cookie and make certain alterations to the DOM even before the cookie is validated, but it could never assume whether you, for example, starred or unstarred a repository.

Am I missing anything here or is that really simply the limitation of the technology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you'd want to serve the site to authenticated users via a service worker as then it can quickly do the initial render custom to the user. This pattern is often called the App Shell Model https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/architecture/app-shell

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, App Shell Model informs the design in such a way that the shell, aside from knowing logged in or not (based on a cookie or localStorage), does not contain user specifics like the Github example I mentioned. It's a small tradeoff but with the correct design hardly important I guess.